# Read a cfd/text File and Delete Blank Lines

Tags: vb6

Hi I'm trying to create a function in VB6.0 to read lines from a cfd file and then delete the blank rows from that file? Can anyone please help me with that?

What I'm trying to say is.

```
/The file is already read through a ReadStream
/Once its read I would like to identify the blank rows 
/ delete them.take the blank rows
```

I tried bunch of different approaches here is the last one:

```
Do Until Len(msLineRecord) = ReadStream.AtEndOfStream 
    msLineRecord = Replace(msLineRecord, vbNewLine & vbNewLine, vbNewLine) 
    msLineRecord = Len(msLineRecord)
Loop
```

Also

```
Do Until ReadStream.AtEndOfStream
    If LenB(Trim$(strLine)) = 0 Then
        If Not bFoundBlankLine Then
            Print #2, strLine bFoundBlankLine = True
        End If
    Else
        Print #2, strLine
    End If
Loop
Close ff1
Close ff2
Kill "C:\temp\blank lines.txt"
Name "C:\temp\MyTemp.tmp" As "C:\temp\blank lines.txt"
```

Comment: Open a temporary file and as you read lines from the source, if they are not blank write them to the temporary file. When you're done delete the original file and rename the temporary file to the original file name.

Comment: Thanks can you also show me code, please.

Comment: Nope, You haven't provided any code for me to work with.

Comment: I tried bunch of different approaches here is the last one:                                
          Do Until Len(msLineRecord) = ReadStream.AtEndOfStream
        msLineRecord = Replace(msLineRecord, vbNewLine & vbNewLine, vbNewLine)
        msLineRecord = Len(msLineRecord)
    Loop

Comment: Do Until ReadStream.AtEndOfStream

        If LenB(Trim$(strLine)) = 0 Then
            If Not bFoundBlankLine Then
                Print #2, strLine
                bFoundBlankLine = True
            End If
        Else
            Print #2, strLine
        End If
    Loop

    Close ff1
    Close ff2
    Kill "C:\temp\blank lines.txt"
    Name "C:\temp\MyTemp.tmp" As "C:\temp\blank lines.txt"

Comment: Please edit your question to add code. It does not format well and is difficult to read in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using the **FileSystemObject** to open and read through the your file so I am going to assume that a cfd file is a plain text file. I AM NOT INCLUDING ERROR HANDLING. You should be able to do that.

```
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim fsoSourceStream As TextStream
Dim fsoTempStream As TextStream
Dim fsoFile As File
Dim strLine As String

' Create a temporary text file, and return a reference to a TextStream
Set fsoTempStream = fso.CreateTextFile("some_path\temporary.txt", True) ' the True parameter overwrites the file if it already exists

' Open the source file for reading and return a reference to the TextStream
Set fsoFile = fso.GetFile("some_path\my_file.cfd")
Set fsoSourceStream = fsoFile.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading)

' Loop through the lines writing the lines that are not blank to the temp file
Do While Not fsoSourceStream.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = fsoSourceStream.ReadLine
    If Len(strLine) > 0 Then
        fsoTempStream.WriteLine strLine
    End If
Loop

fsoSourceStream.Close
fsoTempStream.Close

fso.DeleteFile("some_path\my_file.cfd") ' Delete the source file
' Rename the temporary file to the source file name
Set fsoFile = fso.GetFile("some_path\temporary.txt")
fsoFile.Name = "some_path\my_file.cfd"

' Clean up
Set fso = Nothing
Set fsoFile = Nothing
Set fsoSourceStream = Nothing
Set fsoTempStream = Nothing
```